# how to clear express-session as part of logout in nodeApp

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session, express-session

We are using express-session for storing the information in our node applicaiton.
Example:
req.session.userinfo = userObj;

How to clear the session information as part of logout?   Please suggest us if any standards way of clearing the session information as part of logout

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is `req.session.destroy()` - https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessiondestroycallback